# Wagtail PageQuerySet Querying

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-pageurl, wagtail-slugurl

I have an NewsIndexPage and a NewsPage ,  on the Wagtail Admin using NewsIndexPage i have created  a tree node where i have 
NewsIndexPage-->Corporate(this is NewsIndexPage) and i have Travel (NewsInndexPage)
like this 
 Corporate-->Travel--> News Stories

I can query as so  `NewsPage.objects.live().order_by('-last_published_at')`
how can i query and display stories from Travel 
i have done so `NewsPage.objects.live().filter(slug='corporate').order_by('-last_published_at')`  but how  can i do that for  Travel as `NewsPage.objects.live().filter(slug='travel').order_by('-last_published_at')` --- this doesnt work , how can i filter and get all  pages on the Travel -->NewsPage(This holds the news stories)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
`NewsIndexPage.objects.get(slug='travel').get_children()`